# Best practice for storing product images?

Tags: database, performance, optimization, storage, e-commerce

There can be 100k+ records in products table. Each product may may have around 100 images (because product may be multi-variation) and each image has thumbnail created programmaticaly. Thus, we got (100k+ product) * 100 * 2 = 20000k+ images.

Thus, I want to have best practice for storing and managing these images.

I have two solution:

1. creating main folder for product and creating some structure inside that product. Only save main product path at the products table.

```
products/product_1/images/folder_1/main.jpg
products/product_1/images/folder_1/thumbnail.jpg
products/product_1/images/folder_2/main.jpg
products/product_1/images/folder_2/thumbnail.jpg
```

> I have applied this solution. It becomes tricky when editing product.

2. creating media database table and storing all paths there. This is easy setup.
   But I concern about performance.

So which is the best solution or there are other ones ?

Comment: You should add information about how you want to have access to them. You could just put them all in the same folder and have a few tables, e.g. product, product_image, product_image_type, containing links. If you want the images to be accessed via a webserver, then you need to decide if they are all public images or not. If not, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should **try storing it in database with 1st option**. And your question about the thing where after editing product it becomes tricky and messy, I think that you should **use some sort of Id of the product to set the path** so that changes in names and other properties wouldn't affect the path of product.

Also, **second method would become messy** because **a product has multiple images and managing all those images in a single folder and if editing names it would result in many editing in database to change paths and names etc.